# Why can't I cast a ref parameter?

Tags: c#

I have a method with a ref control type parameter which I want to call by passing a ref button type parameter.

Well the compiler doesn't accept this, I have to change the ref control type to ref button type.

Why ?

Comment: I'm curious if the `ref` is even necessary considering you're passing an object.

Comment: Hmm, programmernovice. Might want to consider a new handle. You still gonna want that handle in 5 years?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get around some of the typing limitations with generics.

```
void Test<T>(ref T control)
   where T: Control
{
}
```

Now you can call:

```
Button b = new Button() 
Test(b);
```

You can pass a reference of any type into it that derives from control.

Real life scenario:

```
 protected static void BindCollection<T>(
        T list
        , ref T localVar
        , ref ListChangedEventHandler eh // the event handler
        , ListChangedEventHandler d) //the method to bind the event handler if null
        where T : class, IBindingList
    {
        if (eh == null)
            eh = new ListChangedEventHandler(d);

        if (list != null && list != localVar)
        {
            if (localVar != null)
                localVar.ListChanged -= eh;

            localVar = list;

            list.ListChanged += eh;
        }
        else if (localVar != null && list == null)
        {
            localVar.ListChanged -= eh;
            localVar = list;
        }
    }

public override BindingList<ofWhatever> Children
    {
        get{//..}
        set
        {
           //woot! a one line complex setter 
           BindCollection(value, ref this._Children, ref this.ehchildrenChanged, this.childrenChanged);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the solution whereas I just asked why so it's great, will choose your answer as best.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that... got ahead of myself.

Comment: While I really like the generic-ref-trick, I find your usage not so good practice. One should usually avoid (public) setters for list-type properties. In what scenarios do you use the code?

Comment: i would generally agree, and in most cases it is actually private and i call the method from the lazy loaded getter.  I have a lot of objects who have child collections that are lazy loaded, and this model(while i truncated it for viewing on SO) ensures that i get consistent binding without copying and pasting code.

Comment: The first part of the solution is exactly what I needed. T is a base interface, and I was able to pass in a "ref control" of type derived interface. I could not set "control" to null, but `control = default(T)` did the trick.

Answer (score 30):

Because this will cause many problems ...

```
public void DoDarkMagic(ref Control control)
{
    control = new TextBox();
}

public void Main()
{
    Button button = new Button();

    DoDarkMagic(ref button);

    // Now your button magically became a text box ...
}
```

Comment: I think a little more explanation would help him out. I suspect that he's not clear on some stuff, his example has code smell.

Answer (score 8):

From the C# specification:

> When a formal parameter is a reference
>   parameter, the corresponding argument
>   in a method invocation must consist of
>   the keyword ref followed by a
>   variable-reference (§12.3.3) of the
>   same type as the formal parameter

Answer (score 3):

In general, ref requires an exact type match, no explicit or implicit conversions allowed.

Show some code so we can discus the details and alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

According to C# spec:

> When a formal parameter is a reference parameter, the corresponding argument in a method invocation must consist of the keyword ref  followed by a variable-reference (§5.3.3) of the same type as the formal parameter.

Otherwise it is possible that a value of inappropriate type (to your button filed reference to checkbox instance) will be assigned to a variable you pass.

Answer (score 1):

While it wasn't possible in 2009, it is now with `ref Unsafe.As<TFrom, TTo>(ref TFrom source)`. You're on your own here, so make sure to use tests and assertions to verify that what you're doing is correct (and will remain correct in future .Net versions). I was looking for this question because I wanted atomic operations on a `[Flags]` `enum` but `Interlocked` doesn't provide methods for non primitive structs.