# Generic class where T is base class: error passing variable of type T as reference

Tags: c#

I have a class A which has a few subclasses.

```
public class A
{
    public void FooA(ref A obj)
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

I also have a generic class `B<T>` where T must be a subclass of A

```
public class B<T> where T : A
{
    public T variable;

    public void FooB(ref T obj)
    {
        variable.FooA(ref obj);
    }

}
```

When I try calling the FooA inside FooB I get the following error:

> Cannot convert 'ref T' to 'ref A'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't be safely done. The caller of `FooB` may have a variable that can only reference a `C`, some specific subtype of `A`. But for all we know, `FooA` may assign an `A`, or a `D`, or any other subtype of A.

Comment: You should find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428996/why-cant-i-cast-a-ref-parameter